# decouple software components via nameconvention

Tags: c#, architecture, decoupling, multi-tier

I'm currently evaluating alternatives to refactor a drivermanagement.

In my multitier architecture I have

Baseclass

- `DAL.Device` //my entity

Interfaces

- `BL.IDriver` //handles the dataprocessing between application and device
- `BL.IDriverCreator` //creates an `IDriver` from a `Device`
- `BL.IDriverFactory` //handles the driver creation requests

Every specialization of `Device` has a corresponding `IDriver` implementation and a corresponding `IDriverCreator` implementation.

At the moment the mapping is fix via a type check within the business layer / `DriverFactory`. That means every new driver needs a) changing code within the `DriverFactory` and b) referencing the new `IDriver` implementation / assembly. On a customers point of view that means, every new driver, used or not, needs a complex revalidation of their hardware environment, because it's a critical process.

My first inspiration was to use a caliburn micro like nameconvention

see [Caliburn.Micro: Xaml Made Easy](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=View%2FViewModel%20Naming%20Conventions)

- `BL.RestDriver`
- `BL.RestDriverCreator`
- `DAL.RestDevice`

After receiving the `RestDevice`within the `IDriverFactory` I can load all driver dlls via reflection and do a namesplitting/comparing (extracting the xx from xxDriverCreator and xxDevice)

Another idea would be a custom attribute (which also leads to comparing strings).

My question: is that a good approach above layer borders? If not, what would be a good approach?

Comment: probably this question belongs to [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @YuliamChandra, no as CodeReview deals only with **existing working code**